# VirtualBox Host - Ram Question - Mem Free Vs Mem Available - Possible Mem Leak?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, ram

I'm wondering if our system has lots of free RAM, or if its almost out. I read [here regarding MemAvailable](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=34e431b0ae398fc54ea69ff85ec700722c9da773) but I am wondering how it applies to VirtualBox as I am sure thats the reason the numbers I get from the following commands differ so much.

```
cat /proc/meminfo | grep Mem && free -lg
MemTotal:       32771584 kB
MemFree:          203372 kB
MemAvailable:   27739104 kB
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:            31         31          0          0          0         25
Low:            31         31          0
High:            0          0          0
-/+ buffers/cache:          5         25
Swap:           31          0         31
```

We have only allocated about 15GB of RAM to our VM's and the sytem has 32GB's. **Does the above output seem normal**, do we have 27 GB of free RAM to allocate? Or are we almost out? Or perhaps a memory leak? Any ideas are welcome! Thank you in advnace

```
Ubuntu 14.04
Virtualbox 5
x64
32 GB RAM
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 25Gb free;  it's all being used as cache.   The free output is most telling:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
[...]
-/+ buffers/cache:          5         25
```

See http://www.linuxatemyram.com/ for more details.

Comment: Nice to know I don't have anything to fix!